# How do you select a link from a drop down window with PHPUnit & Selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, pear

Hi I am beginning to start automating some tests.  I am trying to verify that certain submenu options exist when you hover over the dropdown menu.  But I get an error returned from PHPUnit:

PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'WIN-5FCJ9IIGCSP', ip: '192.168.31.128', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2',
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 9fad5b24-2a1e-472d-bb36-b8914b3a92c2
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=27.0.1}]

I have been searching the web and would appreciate any help
Thanks
Conor

Answer (score 0):

Before you search for the element(dropdown)
Try to put a:

```
sleep(3); // This will make it sleep for 3seconds
```

Or waitForElementPresent could work aswell.
And see what you get. Selenium might think that the page is already loaded and tries to find the element which isn't loaded yet:  Element is not currently visible

Answer (score 0):

I'm also at the very beginning of selenium, but here is a solution I wrote for clicking a dropdown element

```
for($tick=0 ; $tick<5 ; $tick++){
    $this->moveto($this->byCssSelector('#dropDown'));
}

$this->byLinkText("Settings")->click();
```

If I didn't wrap the `moveto()` with the for loop, it would just hover momentarily and didn't work, so the ticking kept it hovered.

I suggest you to use the `waitUntil()` function and check when your element is `displayed()`